# ElasticSearch / Lucene query strict matching child fields

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

Say I have an Elastic search index of songs, and the `artist` field can contain multiple artists.

I want to find Michael Jacson songs, so I might use a query like this:

`artist.first_name: Michael AND artist.last_name: Jackson`

However I recently noticed that might return me a result like this:

```
{
    title: 'Some Janet Jackson Song feat. Michael Bublé',
    artist: [
        {first_name: 'Michael', last_name: 'Bublé'}
        {first_name: 'Janet', last_name: 'Jackson'}
    ]
}
```

Note I have one artist with the first name "Micheal" and another with the the last name "Jackson" so technically this song matches my query.

I don't know the right words to search for this issue. Is this a problem with how my search index is structured? Can I formulate my query a way to avoid this? Ideally I don't want to have a `full_name` field with these values concatenated or anything like that.

Comment: yes, it's possible to fix, could you share your mappings just in case?